# Norm and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, inner-products

Is always square of the norm of a vector is same as the inner product of that vector with itself? In Probability theory we frequently use $L^P$ norm: $\|X\|=E^{1/p}\left(X^p\right)$. But don't we still use $E(XY)$ as the inner product? In that case, $\langle x,x\rangle=EX^2$ which is not equal to the square of the norm when $p\neq2$.

Comment: Some norms come from an inner product, some don't. The $L^P$ norm does only when $P=2$.

Comment: Okay. So in general, square of the norm is not equal to the inner product with itself. Right?

Comment: As Ethan said, if you have an inner product then $<x, x>$ is the square of a norm. On the other hand, a norm does not have to come from an inner product e.g. for p = 1 there is no inner product creating the norm.

Comment: See my answer, written while @Paul was commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not always make sense to refer to "the" norm and "the" inner product.

You should when what you mean is the usual inner product and its corresponding norm - the $L^2$ norm when there is one.

But whenever you have "an" inner product it defines a norm. Spaces can have more than one inner product, so more than one norm that comes from an inner product. For example, on $\mathbb{R}^2$ the inner product
$$
\langle (a,b),(c,d)\rangle = ac + 2bd
$$
defines the norm in which 
$$
\lVert (a,b)\rVert^2 = a^2 + 2b^2
$$

but the norm defined by
$$
\lVert (a,b) \rVert  = |a| + |b|
$$
does not come from any inner product.